# Is there a more efficient way to sort these dictionaries

Tags: c#, sorting, data-structures

So I queried a database to create a collection called "activities" and these are calls that have a related question and a related date. I need to return the top 3 questions asked if the activity date is with 0-3 months, 4-12 months, or more than a year. I created an algorithm but for learning purposes I thought there might be a better way to efficiently sort these activities. This is my code

```cs
var activities = ctx.Activities.Where(a => a.SiteID == propID && a.ActivityTypeName == "Call" && a.ParcelData.Parcel_LetterTracking.LMailDate != null)       
    .Select(x => new 
    {                 
       callDate = x.DateTimeEntry,
       mailDate = x.Contact.OwnerContact.ParcelDatas.FirstOrDefault(a => a.OwnerContactID == x.Contact.OwnerContact.OOwnerID).Parcel_LetterTracking.LMailDate,
       question = x.FAQs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ActivityID == x.ActivityID).FAQ_Library.FaqNum  + " - " + 
                  x.FAQs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ActivityID == x.ActivityID).FAQ_Library.Question       
    }).AsEnumerable();


// create a dictionary of Key = the question and Value = the count of occurences in activities for each time frame. 
Dictionary<string, int> calls3month = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Dictionary<string, int> calls6month = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Dictionary<string, int> calls12month = new Dictionary<string, int>();
// counters for number of calls between each range
int numberOfCalls3Months = 0; 
int numberOfCalls4to6Months = 0;
int numberOfCalls12Months = 0;
foreach (var call in activities)
{
    // if calldate - maildate is 3 months, 4-12 months or 12+ months 
    TimeSpan deltaOfDates = call.callDate.Subtract((DateTime)call.mailDate); 
    if (deltaOfDates.Days < 91 && deltaOfDates.Days > 0)
    {                       
        if (calls3month.TryGetValue(call.question, out int count))
        {
            calls3month[call.question] = count + 1;
        }
        else {
            calls3month.Add(call.question, 1);
        }
        numberOfCalls3Months++; 
    }
    else if (deltaOfDates.Days < 365 && deltaOfDates.Days >= 91)
    {                     
        if (calls6month.TryGetValue(call.question, out int count))
        {
            calls6month[call.question] = count + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            calls6month.Add(call.question, 1);
        }
        numberOfCalls4to6Months++;
    }
    else if (deltaOfDates.Days >= 365)
    {
        if (calls12month.TryGetValue(call.question, out int count))
        {
            calls12month[call.question] = count + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            calls12month.Add(call.question, 1);
        }
        numberOfCalls12Months++;
    }
}
//grab top 3 questions asked. Key = the question, value = the frequency
var topCalls3month = calls3month.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value).Take(3).ToArray();
var topCalls6month = calls6month.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value).Take(3).ToArray();
var topCalls12month = calls12month.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value).Take(3).ToArray();
```

Would it be faster to sort these as I enumerate through the activities collection? If(dictionary.value is in the top 3 add it to the top of the list)
What is a strategy I could use to do that?

At the end when I use orderbyDescending, I feel like this is inefficient and the dictionaries should be sorted coming out of the foreach loop/

Comment: Without looking at any specifics, I think you could do Parallel.For(0, activities.Length, (i) => { /*Do checks...*/ }); utilizing ConcurrentDictionary https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Will not affect performance but you can simplify block for increasing count `calls6month[call.question] = calls6month.GetValueOrDefault() + 1;`

Comment: Sometimes it's best to just do it through the db query.

Comment: @TerryTyson I thought about that but I need the different dates in different lists. Is there a way I can organize them in one query (instead of 3 queries) ? If I had to do 3 queries with  .Where(date time is in 3 months/6 months/12 months) wouldn't that be less efficient?

Comment: Unless you have millions of records, performance bottle neck in this function would be a sql query. Code is readable and clean enough to keep it as it is until you start getting noticeable performance issues.

Comment: You can execute separate query for every case(range of days) asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could avoid the sorts (i.e. `OrderByDescending`) by running a [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) on the resulting dictionaries. [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) is an O(n) algorithm, which is asymptotically more efficient than sorting. You can probably find plenty of implementations online.

Whether using the selection algorithm would actually be faster enough to worry about is another question. Even if your arrays contain a million items, the difference between the selection algorithm and the sort will probably be less than a second. Do you really care if you get your answer a few milliseconds faster?